# Android code does not seem to run synchronously

Tags: android, cordova

I would like to know why my Android code is not running Synchronously.

I am overriding Cordova's `Mainactivity` class's `onCreate` to execute custom code when the app starts.

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // 1. Show loading dialog
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Dialog loadingDialog = Loading.createLoadingDialog(this, display, getLoadingHTMLPath());
    loadingDialog.show();

    loadUrl(launchUrl);

    // 2. Copy bunch of files (this takes some time)
    copyFiles();
  }
```

I am expecting the app to show the loading dialog first, and then copy the files. However, I see a black screen on the app launch. Then the app copies all the files. It is only after that the app displays the loading dialog.

Why is second part of the code running first? Any suggestions on how to get the dialog to display first?

*Edit*

This was my initial solution that worked.

```
Thread onAppStartTask = new Thread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    copyFiles();
  }
});

onAppStartTask.start();
```

Comment: because it's in one thread and block the UI thread. use AsyncTask for background processing ( show the loading bar and copy the files )

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira - That kind of make sense. But how does `copyFiles()` block the UI thread? Hasn't `loadingDialog.show()` already finished by the time I call `copyFiles()`?

Comment: "Hasn't loadingDialog.show() already finished . . ."  Yes, `show()` has finished.  But `show()` doesn't show the dialog; it adds the task to show the dialog to the end of the main thread's work queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the thing is, you are running the code synchronously. That's the problem. Android has exactly one thread for displaying and modifying the UI, so the call to `copyFiles()` will prevent any further action in the UI until it finishes.

The `show()` call doesn't occur instantaneously - `onStart()` and `onResume()` need to be called first - and the screen turns black because it's not able to draw anything while your app is stuck in `onCreate()`. The highly recommended solution is putting the file-loading logic in a background thread and periodically updating the ui with its progress.

Try this for starters and see if it works.

```java
cordovaInterface.getThreadPool().execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        copyFiles();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Android has exactly one thread for displaying and modifying the UI." So does `copyFiles()` run on the same thread as the UI thread, and hence block it?

Comment: Your solution works. Can you have a look at my solution, and tell me if there is a difference? I have included it in the original question.

Comment: @MikeC yep, that's right. Your changed code looks good to me. I think you _might_ get better performance by using an existing ThreadPool instead of explicitly creating a new Thread, but at this stage in your app development it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Learned something new.